# Calculating speed using core motion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geolocation, core-motion

Here is my code for finding speed. It's working fine into simulator (freeway Drive), but in actual device if I am stopped or moving slowly then it's updating slowly like updates in 8 to 10 seconds.

```
CLLocation *locationLast=[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].arrayLocations lastObject];

CLLocation *locationSecondLast=[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].arrayLocations objectAtIndex:[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].arrayLocations count]-2];
CLLocationSpeed speed = locationLast.speed - locationSecondLast.speed;
lblSpeedDiffrence.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f MPH", (float)(speed * 2.23693629)];
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [locationLast.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:locationSecondLast.timestamp];
lblTimeDiffrence.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f seconds", timeDifference];
double HardAcceleration = (speed * 2.23693629) / timeDifference;
if (HardAcceleration>0)
{
     if (HardAcceleration>10)
         lblStatus.text = @"Hard Acceleration";
     else
         lblStatus.text = @"Acceleration";
}
else if (HardAcceleration<0)
{
     if (HardAcceleration<-10)
         lblStatus.text = @"Hard Deceleration";
     else
         lblStatus.text = @"Deceleration";
}
else
{
     lblStatus.text = @"Neutral";
}
```

This code is for getting location updates and speed based on GPS.
I want to get realtime speed like speedometer using inbuilt sensor of iPhone/iPad.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Let us know what issues you are facing or what kind of errors you are getting.

Comment: @mqpasta I'm not facing any errors but i want accurate speed, while testing my code into actual device.This code working fine into simulator but not in actual device. Any suggestion for finding speed using core motion (Accelerometer)